# Javascript slideshow that changes background img of an element

Tags: javascript, css

trying to make a slideshow that utilizes background-image: property. Here is what I have so far.

```
<div id="headerContent">
        <div id="rightArrow"></div><!-- end of rightArrow-->
        <div id="leftArrow"></div><!-- end of leftArrow-->
    </div><!-- end of headerContent-->

document.getElementById("headerContent").setAttribute('style', 'background:url(images/home-header-1.png) no-repeat !important');

document.getElementById("rightArrow").addEventListener("click", changeImageRight);


function changeImageRight () {
    var i = 0;

    if(i == 0) {
        document.getElementById("headerContent").setAttribute('style', 'background:url(images/home-header-1.png) no-repeat !important');
        i++;
    }
    else if (i == 1)
     {
        document.getElementById("headerContent").setAttribute('style', 'background:url(images/home-header-2.png) no-repeat !important');
        i++;
    }
    else if (i == 2) {
        document.getElementById("headerContent").setAttribute('style', 'background:url(images/home-header-3.png) no-repeat !important');
        i++;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("headerContent").setAttribute('style', 'background:url(images/home-header-1.png) no-repeat !important');
        i++;
    }

}
```

as you can see I increment i++ to change the background image. However, as it stands this doesn't do anything, and no image is displayed. And I included the !important attribute because it's the only way I can get the placeholder img to show at the start.

Comment: The first line of the function sets the *local* `i` variable to `0`, so only the first `if` condition can ever be true.

Comment: `document.getElementById("headerContent").style.backgroundImage = "url(images/home-header-1.png)"`

Comment: Setting the style attribute will totally overwrite it, just like `.cssText`. You should use `Element.style.background` instead. Just a comment.

Comment: Self incrementing functions look more like `var count = (function(){ var c = 0; return function(){ return ++c;} }());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should think more like this:

```
var changeImageRight = (function(){
  var i = 0;
  return function(){
    // better code than you wrote here 
    // now you can expect i to hold scope
  }
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are declaring the index variable `i` inside your `changeImageRight` method. Meaning that each time the method is called, `i` always starts out as set to `0`.

You want to have the value of `i` persist between each call to `changeImageRight`. To do so, just declare the variable outside the function. You can do so by moving the line `var i = 0;` above the line with `function changeImageRight () {`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to declare variable `i` globally.

like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    //GLOBAL DECLARATION
    var i = 0;

    document.getElementById("headerContent").setAttribute('style', 'background:url(images/home-header-1.png) no-repeat !important');

    document.getElementById("rightArrow").addEventListener("click", changeImageRight);


    function changeImageRight () {

        if(i == 0) {
            document.getElementById("headerContent").setAttribute('style', 'background:url(images/home-header-1.png) no-repeat !important');
            i++;
        }
        else if (i == 1)
         {
            document.getElementById("headerContent").setAttribute('style', 'background:url(images/home-header-2.png) no-repeat !important');
            i++;
        }
        else if (i == 2) {
            document.getElementById("headerContent").setAttribute('style', 'background:url(images/home-header-3.png) no-repeat !important');
            i++;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("headerContent").setAttribute('style', 'background:url(images/home-header-1.png) no-repeat !important');
            i++;
        }

    } 
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="headerContent">
            <div id="rightArrow"></div><!-- end of rightArrow-->
            <div id="leftArrow"></div><!-- end of leftArrow-->
    </div><!-- end of headerContent-->
</body>
</html>
```

I used used internal JavaScript. You can place this JavaScript in your external JS file if you have.